# Access to the path is denied error

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

There's a lot of questions floating around on here and the web, however I couldn't resolve my issue with them.

My app pool user is set to NETWORK SERVICE, and I've verified on the folder that it is has full access (Every permission is checked). However, when I initiate a GET request to download a file it says `Access to the path is denied`.

I'm using .NET 4 and webforms on IIS6.

[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem ended up being that the file itself didn't have the `NETWORK SERVICE` user assigned to it as I dragged the files into that directory without having the web site create them.

I was under the impression that setting the user on a directory would affect files within.